Hammer of Runic Focus
In The Book of Many Things, there is a Hammer of Runic Focus.
The illustration is awesome and its general theme and function seem interesting.
However, it seems in every way to be significantly inferior to a standard +3 Warhammer (which shares its rarity) but also requires attunement.
Am I missing some potential use or interaction that attunement offsets?

It looks cooler.

A lot of items from BoMT have rarity completely unrelated to what the item actually does.

The Hammer of Runic Focus is inferior, even if it has the same rarity as a +3 warhammer.
You did not miss anything. Rarity is more of a guideline for pricing and relative power, but is not always perfect. And in that particular case, one item is clearly better than the other.
But the thing is, players don't necessarly get to choose which hammer they'll get. And if they get a Hammer of Runic Focus first.. well, it's already something, until they eventually find a +3 warhammer.
